# What mechanisms would allow a naked singularity to glow?

Tags: black-holes, singularities

I was reading about why there should be a limit on how fast a blackhole can spin but assuming a naked singularity is real and is exposed, my question is how does it glows? Blackbody? or hawking radiation? or accelerates charged particles using powerful magnetic field? I reckon it must depends on whether it is a point-like or ring like structure, right?

Comment: related or duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/455726/why-exactly-are-singularities-avoided-or-deleted-in-physics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody knows the way it glows.

If classical (i.e. not quantum) general relativity asserts there is a curvature singularity somewhere, then you should interpret this as the statement, "here there is something going on which this theory cannot describe; very likely some sort of quantum theory will be required, but exactly what is not known." You sometimes see rather fanciful pictures of random household objects emerging from naked singularities. I don't think anyone really thinks that is what might come out---it is just a way of saying we have no idea what the physics may be in this case.

It remains entirely plausible that the natural world is so configured that naked singularities never arise, but some studies in quantum field theory suggest maybe they can arise, so this is unknown too.