# Spacetime metrics extended to negative radius

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, kerr-metric

In the Kerr metric
$$
 ds^2=\left(1-\frac{2Mr}{\rho^2}\right)dt^2+\frac{4Mar\sin^2\theta}{\rho^2}dtd\varphi-\frac{\rho^2}{\Delta}dr^2-\rho^2d\theta^2-\left(r^2+a^2+\frac{2Ma^2r\sin^2\theta}{\rho^2}\right ) \sin^2\theta d\phi^2
$$
with
$$
\rho^2=r^2+a^2\cos^2\theta,\quad \Delta=r^2-2Mr+a^2
$$
the coordinate $r$ can be extended to negative values.
This because a variable which behaves like a radius can be built as
$$
R=r\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2\theta /r^2}
$$
and only asymptotically far from the source we have that $R\sim r$.
Everywhere else the coordinate $r$ is just a coordinate, and therefore can take also negative values.

1. There is a physical meaning to this? Or is just a mathematical consequence of the form of the metric?

The extension to negative value of $r$ is possible also on other spacetimes, such as Simpson-Visser, which looks a lot like Schwarzschild metric, but also in this case we can expand to $r=0$ and negative $r$, since the metric is regular for any $r$.

2. Why can't we then expand Schwarzschild to negative $r$, but without $r=0$? (just from a mathematical point of view)

and

3. Given an arbitrary metric, when can we expand it to negative $r$?

Comment: It can be done, see [here](https://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/insidebh/penrose.html#kerr) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/471419/metric-diameter-of-a-ring-singularity) or [here](http://www.madore.org/~david/math/kerr.html#course.negspace), it's called the negative space

Comment: @Yukterez [here](http://www.madore.org/~david/math/kerr.html#course.negspace) gives details on negative space, but not on when or how can be constructed

Comment: In the Eddington Finkelstein style [Kerr Schild coordinates](https://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?p=451#p497) you can plot trajectories through the ring singularity into the negative r region. You can also transform to [Null coordinates](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/63.html) and use the u,v-axes tilted by 45°.

Comment: @Yukterez ok, but my question is more about the mathematical aspect of how we see that the negative space exists

Comment: I know, but since I can't answer your whole question I must restrict myself to these comments. Roy Black himself although does not believe in it, see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nypav68tq8Q&t=2907s)

Comment: @Yukterez extremely interesting lecture, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In general, what you describe is done, even in the case of black holes. Barring infinity identifications, the region with a negative radius is in some cases interpreted as another universe. In the case of black holes in the following diagram taken from [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJQND.gif), the region denoted as a "parallel universe" is the one with a negative radius. The interesting aspect is that the radial point at which the two universes meet is at $r = 2M$, since beyond this radius the radial and time coordinate switches their roles, so that $r = 0$ is at the top of the diagram. Given a general metric, nothing a priori prohibits extending the coordinates, even to negative radii, barring degeneracies or singularities. It obviously depends on the physical meaning you want to assign to the metric.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJQND.gif) [https://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/insidebh/penrose.html](https://jila.colorado.edu/%7Eajsh/insidebh/penrose.html)

[image: Penrose Diagram]